# Why does music sound slightly sharper when played through headphones?

Tags: pitch, headphones

Why does my music appear to very slightly **rise in pitch when I switch from computer speakers to computer headphones** (cheap foam, mic boom integrated)?

Ideas:

1. Might this be due to a pressure change on my eardrum as [another poster noticed when he yawns](https://music.stackexchange.com/questions/23829/why-does-music-seem-to-transpose-when-i-yawn)?
2. Maybe my headphones actually change the frequency of the output?  I can't picture how that would work...
3. Maybe I'm perceiving the doppler shift as I move the speaker toward my ear, and I'm distracted from the reverse shift by the mechanics of putting the earphones in place?

Comment: Re: 1. I once had an ear infection that had me hearing left & right at about ¼ tone apart, for a week. I wouldn't have believed it possible if I hadn't experienced it.

Comment: It's a known thing, apparently: http://www.healthyhearing.com/report/51055-Understanding-diplacusis  Very weird!  Probably unrelated to this question, though.

Answer (score 2):

Most likely you are either imagining the pitch change or you are unusually sensitive to pitch, which is a subjective interpretation that is *also dependent on volume*. So you might try turning down the volume when you switch to headphones.

You might also or instead hearing a change in frequency balance and interpreting it as a slight pitch change. All speaker and headphone systems have different frequencies they emphasize, so you will hear a difference any time you change your playback system.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I used to mix with closed-cup headphones, and I did notice after extended wearing that all the pitches seem to have gone sharp, compared to when I checked the mix without them afterwards.

Makes sense since warmer air is less dense, I guess.

I switched to open-cup headphones last year, and the side-effect has lessened a lot.  I can keep them on for over 30 min. at a time w/o pitch-shifts.  I was surprised how quickly the air inside headphones heat up once you put 'em on, but what do I know!